# simple Jquery animation don't work Works on Jsfiddle

Tags: jquery

Are going crazy about this now...

I'm trying to get an animation that work on jsFiddle to work local/ftp but nothing happens.

I have include ALL this library's

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

I can run an animation that has the function  `$(this).hide(` ... but as i told, not the animate func.

This is the script I'm using.

```
$(".wrapper").mouseenter( function() {
    $(this).animate({
        left: -1*$(".leftbox").width()
    }, 500);
});

$(".wrapper").mouseleave( function() {
    $(this).animate({
        left: "0px"
    }, 500);
});
```

And here is the jsFiddle that I'm copy-paste into my index page. not changing anything.
http://jsfiddle.net/ewNpL/1/

Comment: What exactly is it not doing correctly?  When I view it in chrome, it slides to the "stuff to reveal" section on mouse over and when I mouse out it goes back.  Is this not what you want?

Comment: try wrapping ur code inside the ready handler like `$(function(){//your code});`

Comment: What's your browser's name and version?

Comment: why are you loading jquery twice??

Comment: Why are you including jQuery twice?

Comment: Apropos of nothing, I would also use `.stop()` before `.animate` in your code to account for very fast mouse movements: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ewNpL/597/

Comment: Im using the latest chrome and firefox, the animation works perfectly in jsFiddle but not locally.

Comment: Try using only one version of jQuery.  Adding two different versions could certainly cause weirdness...

Comment: I'm not including Jquery twice, I was just showing all the library's I'm trying with

Comment: In your question you say: `I have include ALL this library's`.  What exactly does that mean?  If all of those libraries are in at the same time, you have included jQuery twice.

Comment: @3nigma Hey! That was the problem :)

Post it as answer and i vote for it :)

Comment: @Dymond posted the answer with a bit of explanation, hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

posting the answer from comments:

try wrapping all your js/jQuery code inside the ready handler like

```
$(function(){
 $(".wrapper").mouseenter( function() {
    $(this).animate({
        left: -1*$(".leftbox").width()
    }, 500);
});

$(".wrapper").mouseleave( function() {
    $(this).animate({
        left: "0px"
    }, 500);
});

});
```

it is recommended to use the ready handler so that before the javascript start showing its magic the DOM should be ready, for the same reason its aslo recommended to mode all the script part after the markup.

Why your code was running fine in fiddle? Because jsfiddle by default wraps the script portion inside the ready handler....